# Displaying real-number values in Drupal Charts/Google Charts

Tags: drupal, charts, google-visualization

I'm wanting to get a Drupal/Google Chart on my site that displays real-number values, both in its y-axis and in the hover-over tooltips. The expected values for my chart range from 0 to 1, and default chart, working from the example code, rounds everything to 0 or 1.

Here's the code:

```
  $clickthrough_chart = array(
    '#type' => 'chart',
    '#chart_type' => 'column',
    '#title' => t('Clickthrough'),
  );
  $clickthrough_chart['Clickthrough'] = array(
    '#type' => 'chart_data',
    '#title' => t('Clickthrough'),
    '#data' => $clickthrough_data,
  );
  $clickthrough_chart['xaxis'] = array(
    '#type' => 'chart_xaxis',
    '#labels' => $chart_labels,    
  );

  $chart['chart'] = $clickthrough_chart;

  return drupal_render($chart);
```

...and here's typical results its displaying:
[image: Typical Output]

For this example, the $clickthrough_data passed in was the array (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.667, 0.0, 0.2)

Comment: I suspect the Visualization API module for Drupal sets some default formatters on both your data and axis labels.  Check the documentation for the module you are using to see if they allow you to configure these.

Comment: Like many Drupal modules, the documentation is unfortunately very thin. The most useful bit is the example code included in the module. I've searched for telling keywords in the source files, but that hasn't yielded results yet.

Comment: @baudot: please add the exact link of the drupal module you are using, similar to how I did it in my answer just now. That will make your question more accurate. Maybe you know from looking at the code which module it "must be", but others may wonder why a prior comment brings up "Visualization API" (I think I know why, but that's because I also know about that module.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this specific example](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426177#preview1), which is close to what you seem to be looking for. It is part of the [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753) of the [charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, which I recently contributed over there.

If needed, do not hesitate to create an issue in the module's issue queue. As an alternative create a new question on this site (or Drupal Answers) and find a way to let me know about it (eg via some comment in any of my questions or answers around here).

If that is not an answer, then you may find a possible alternative, starting from the [Comparison of charting module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985), which includes information and links about quite a lot of charting related modules in Drupal. If you're aware of other modules not included in it, please update that docu if you can, or let me know about it.

**Be aware**: I'm the maintainer of this module.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `charts_element_info` function in charts.module. It's not always obvious where these values sit in the chart array you create, but here's an example for a solution like you require. See `#decimal_count`

```
  $chart['coef'] = array(
    '#type' => 'chart_data',
    '#title' => t('Coefficient'),
    '#data' => $data,
    '#decimal_count' => 2,
  );
```